# Button To Download .txt File (PHP & HTML)

Tags: php, html, onclick

Ok so I want to my users to be able to download a `.txt` file with their username on it.

I've checked everywhere, and so far I can't find what I want or if it's even possible.

To give you an example of what I'm trying to do, here is my code:

```
<button type="button">Download All Your Keys On A .txt
<?php
$file = 'logs/$session->username.txt';

if(!file_exists($file)) die("I'm sorry, the file doesn't seem to exist.");

$type = filetype($file); // Get a date and timestamp $today = date("F j, Y, g:i a"); $time = time(); // Send file headers header("Content-type: $type"); header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$filename");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header('Pragma: no-cache'); 
header('Expires: 0'); // Send the file contents.
set_time_limit(0); 
readfile($file);
?>
</button>
```

I'm trying to make it so that when you click the button, it force download's the .txt file configured with:

```
$file = 'logs/$session->username.txt';
```

Sorry if this is confusing and messy, but there's no other way for me to present this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1st, the button does not work like this. You have to send a request to your page to execute the download. 2nd, nothing should appear before `header()`

Comment: you `$file = 'logs/$session->username.txt';` will not expand because its inside a single quote

Comment: @DevZer0 also, there should be some curly braces

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why don't you have this code in a separate file, say `download.php`:

```
<?php
    $file = "logs/{$session->username}.txt";

    if(!file_exists($file)) die("I'm sorry, the file doesn't seem to exist.");

    $type = filetype($file);
    // Get a date and timestamp
    $today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
    $time = time();
    // Send file headers
    header("Content-type: $type");

    //** If you think header("Content-type: $type"); is giving you some problems,
    //** try header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');

    //** Note filename= --- if using $_GET to get the $file, it needs to be "sanitized".
    //** I used the basename function to handle that... so it looks more like:
    //** header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($_GET['mygetvar']));

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={$session->username}.txt");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
    header('Pragma: no-cache'); 
    header('Expires: 0');
    // Send the file contents.
    set_time_limit(0);
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);

    //** If you are going to try and force download a file by opening a new tab via javascipt
    //** (In this code you would replace the onClick() event handler in the html
    //** button with onclick="window.open('www.someurl.com', '_blank');"
    //** - where 'www.someurl.com' is the url to the php page - I keep the file
    //** creation and download handling in the same file, and $_GET the file name
    // - bad practice? Probably, but I never claimed to be an expert),
    //** be sure to include exit(); in this part of the php... 
    //** otherwise leave exit(); out of the code.
    //** If you don't, it will likely break the code, based on my experience.

    //exit();
?>
```

Please note that you have to change the quotes to double quotes, as you use a variable inside the `'`s. So, to expand the variable, change the first line to:

```
$file = "logs/{$session->username}.txt";
```

Here I consider, `$session->username`, as the variable you are trying to refer.

And have this in the HTML:

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='download.php'">Download All Your Keys On A .txt</button>
```

And when you click on this button, it redirects to the `download.php`, that initiates a download of the txt file. As simple as that. But this requires you to have two files. And I don't understand the need for a button here. Why not just use a simple link like this?

```
<a href="download.php">Download All Your Keys On A .txt</a>
```

And if you need, you can style it using CSS.

Comment: @JanDvorak Seriously, *why was I so retarded?* Thanks, updated the answer! :)

Comment: Why not use an ordinary link instead of a javascript button?

Comment: @JanDvorak Suggestion added. :D

Comment: only problem is, it opens the file, it doesn't download it!

Comment: Thanks, best and simplest solution! But you're setting the variable `$file` and using `$filename` in `header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$filename");`. Shouldn't it be `header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$file");`?

Comment: @yves Thanks for spotting it. I have corrected. `:)`

Comment: Any idea as to why when I click download it tells me the file type is html vs txt, when the extension I gave it is a txt?

Comment: @ShanerM13 Check out the header's content type.

Comment: It just says "file" as the type. I would like to keep it dynamic if possible. Not a clue why its adding the .html extension to the end. @Praveen Kumar Purushothaman . I would like to note that I replaced the filename= attribute with the $_GET['download'], which returns newfile.txt. And I also replaced $type (in the content header) to {$type}... which shouldn't have made a difference... but I will check those real quick.

Comment: `header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");` This header fixed it for me... from what I can tell works with all file types. I've test .js, .css, .txt, .png... so it should work with almost anything. In terms of identifying the write type of file... for some reason the file I create on the server... a simple txt file with no html in it, when downloaded does have html in it.

Comment: Well, currently your code gets the content type -> `$type = filetype($file)`, then sets it vai -> `header("Content-type: $type");`. Versus just `header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");`. Maybe you are expecting that $type should return application/octet-stream? If so, it wasn't for me. My new problem is that when I download the file and open it, it contains html code in it... of which I do not tell the server to write into it. Thoughts? Which I understand this thread isn't dedicated to that... so I am looking around, and if I can't find one, will create one.

Comment: I think I needed these `ob_clean(); flush();` before `readfile($file);`. I also had `exit()` and had tried `die()` after `readfile($file);`, which probably was the source of the error. Problem solved. Thank you!

Comment: @ShanerM13 Nice one mate. Do you think this answer can be made better by your contribution? In that case, please go ahead and edit it! 